Distinguishing whole closing tag ("</tag>") and self-closing tag ("<tag ... />") in SAX endElement
I extended org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler. When during the parsing an element closes and my endElement callback executes, I would like to be able to tell whether in the XML the element is closed with a whole closing tag like </tag>, or instead it's an element that opens and closes in the same tag like <tag ... />.
Is there a good way to distinguish between the two cases?
The reason why I would like this is that after the parsing I need to recreate the XML (with some modifications) from the read elements, and I would like that in the resulting XML the elements that have no characters in their body close in the same way as they did in the original XML.
I tried by checking that no characters were received for the current element, as an indication that the element closed on the opening tag itself, with ... />, but that also happens when there is a closing tag without characters in the body (<tag ...></tag>).
EDIT: I cannot agree that this is a duplicate of "Is there a semantic difference between  and  in XML?". That question and its answer only point out that there is no difference between the two ways of closing an element. My question is whether there is a way in SAX to distinguish the two cases.

I have not tested it, but you may use the position from the Location object. If it is the same for both the opening and the closing tag, it is the empty tag. But I am not sure if the location is updated permanently, or only in case of an error. You need to play around with it …

There is no difference between<tag/> and <tag></tag> in XML, so XML tools generally do not distinguish them.  For you to try to do so is a mistake.  Your offered reason is unconvincing.

@kjhughes I assure you that that's my reason though, and I don't understand why that would be a mistake. I expect to be able to parse an XML file and rewrite it closing the tags in the same way I found them closed in the original.

I cannot agree that this is a duplicate of Is there a semantic difference between  and  in XML?. That question and its answer only point out that there is no difference between the two ways of closing an element. My question is whether there is a way in SAX to distinguish the two cases. Even if the answer is no, which sounds likely, it could still be that the two ways of closing are equivalent and yet it's possible to know which one it was. For sure I want to try @tquadrat 's suggestion.

@tquadrat Thanks, I think you are talking about org.xml.sax.Locator.getLineNumber(). It does get updated in the callbacks. Unfortunately, it's not always true that for the self-closing tag the line is the same in startElement and endElement, plus a closing tag can be on the same line as its opening tag (<tag ...></tag>). However, Locator.getColumnNumber() does return different values, it's the column where the tag ends. I will try using both and report here the result.

@Loris: The answer is no (not in anything other than an idiosyncratic, non-interoperable way) and the reason is as given by the duplicate link.  Sometimes the best answer to "how do I do X?" is "don't do X."

@kjhughes For me, that's never the best answer (it's not even an answer). If anything, the best answer to "how do I do it" could be "maybe like this or that, but you shouldn't do it". And maybe even adding "because if you do it, it could cause this or that problem".

I found my solution, I can't post the code as the question is closed but for a self-closing tag - and only for that - the Locator returns the same line and column in startElement and endElement (which by the way is the position after the last parsed char).

@Loris: Your "why shouldn't I" question is answered in the link and its references, but I'll summarize for you: Because the two forms are semantically equivalent, XML parsers do not distinguish them, and there is no good reason for you to either.  A common bad reason is because some part of your system is distinguishing between them.  Propagating that problem rather than fixing its source leads to brittle, non-interoperable systems.
